# After Video is complete on mobile device close video

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, video, youtube

Is there a way to close a video after it is complete from an iPhone?  I have a quiz that requires them to watch a video, and a timer that starts after it completes, but on the mobile device it doesnt close automatically.  I am currently using the YouTube JavaScript API.

Comment: What is the code? What is your problem? Without those we are just guessing what will be next feature film!

Answer (score 0):

Does the `webkitExitFullScreen` function help if bound to the `ended` property for the video: (assuming jQuery, but you can bind the event using addEventListener if you're not using jQuery)

```
$('#video').bind('ended', function(){
    document.getElementById('video').webkitExitFullScreen();
});
```

You will probably want to wrap it in a test for iOS specifically, as I think it's a proprietary extension so you'll want to avoid errors on other browsers...

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLVideoElementClassReference/HTMLVideoElement/HTMLVideoElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/HTMLVideoElement/webkitExitFullscreen